# knapsack with graph connectivity constraints

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problems, pseudo-polynomial

I am looking for a variant of the knapsack problem in which the items are nodes in an undirected graph, and the knapsack must be filled with a connected subgraph. Formally:

- The input is an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$, where each node $v\in V$ has both a size and a value; and a knapsack capacity $C$.
- The goal is to find a subset $U\subseteq V$ such that the sum of sizes of all nodes in $U$ is at most the capacity $C$, and in addition, there is a path between every two nodes in $U$; subject to this, the sum of values of all nodes in $U$ should be as large as possible.

The original problem is NP-hard, but has a pseudopolynomial-time algorithm.
The problem with the additional constraint is definitely NP-hard too; does it have a pseudopolynomial-time algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be a pseudopolynomial-time algorithm; the problem is NP-hard even if all values are given in unary. We can reduce from the $\textsf{Connected Vertex Cover}$ problem in which we need to decide whether a graph has a connected subgraph of at most $k$ vertices touching all edges. This is NP-hard by a simple reduction from standard Vertex Cover (simply add an extra vertex and connect it to everything else).

For our reduction, take the input graph $G = (V, E)$ of $\textsf{Connected Vertex Cover}$ and build $G'$ with vertex set $V \cup E$ and edge set $E \cup \{(v, e) \in V \times E \mid v \in e\}$. Make the size of vertices in $V$ equal to $1$, and the size of the vertices in $E$ equal to $0$. Set the value of the vertices in $E$ equal to $1$, and put value 0 for those in $V$. We set the capacity for the knapsack instance equal to $k$, the desired connected vertex cover size.

Now for any connected vertex cover $S$ of $G$ of size at most $k$,  the subgraph induced by $S \cup E$ in $G'$ has value $|E|$ while respecting the capacity. For the other direction, any connected subgraph $S'$ of $G'$ of value $|E|$ and size at most $k$ must include all vertices in $E$, while not including more than $k$ vertices of $E$. That means that $|S' \cap V| \leq k$, and also that $(S' \cap V)$ is a vertex cover for $G$. It only remains to show that $(S' \cap V)$ is connected in $G$, which is direct, since for any pair of vertices $u, v \in (S' \cap V)$, there was a path $u \to e_1 \to v_1 \to e_2 \to v_2 \to \cdots \to e_\ell \to v$ in $G'$ proving its connectedness, and now $u \to v_1 \to v_2 \to \cdots \to v$ is a path in $G$.